# Почему приложение зависает при включенной вспышке CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH? Camera2API

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Странная ситуация получилась у меня.

Я работаю с [примером гугла `camera2API`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) и мне нужно сделать так, чтоб вспышка срабатывала каждый раз когда юзер делает фото.

Для этого я изменил одну строчку в методе

```
private void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
if (mFlashSupported) {
//            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
    requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,  CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
}
}
```

Я изменил CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH на CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH.

Тестирую я код на трех устройствах `Meizu MX5`, `Samsung S5` и `Samsung S6` так вот что получилось, теперь `Meizu MX5` и `Samsung S5` работают как положено и при каждой фото срабатывает вспышка.

Но для `Samsung S6` такой подход не работает и когда юзер нажимает на кнопку <kbd>Сделать фото</kbd> , то вспышка срабатывает и все... Приложение зависает...

То что я выяснил : метод `setAutoFlash()` вызывается в коде в трех разных методах

1. `captureStillPicture()`
2. `unlockFocus()`
3. `onConfigured()`

Так вот если в методе `captureStillPicture()` заблокировать вызов метода `setAutoFlash()` то приложение работает корректно для `Samsung S6` , но тогда не работает вспышка на `Meizu MX5` и `Samsung S5`.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

В конце концов я нашел решение.

Как я сказал метод `setAutoFlash()` вызывается в трех разных местах в коде.

Этот метод на вход принимает `CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder` так вот если для каждого билда который вызовет этот метод установить один и тот же параметр для вспышки то приложение зависает.

Я взял и локально в каждом методе который вызывал этот метод имплементировал настройки для вспышки , вот так :

1. `unlockFocus()` ->
   `mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);`
2. `onConfigured()` ->
   `mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);`

и для этого метода оставил авто настройки

3. `captureStillPicture()` ->
   `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);`

и сейчас все работает для всех устройств.

Но если кто то знает из за чего так получается пожалуйста напишите в комментариях причину.